# Analysis of a longitudinal study where interventions are received at different time points

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, repeated-measures, panel-data

I have a data set of university students. The university has 8 different assisting programs, mostly like scholarships, for needy students to help them concentrate on their studies. Since it costs a lot of money for the university to run these programs, it opts to evaluate how effective each of these programs is.

It is very important to note that these programs were received by different students at different semesters. Also that the same program was received by different students at different semesters. However, many others didn't apply and hence didn't receive any such program.

I have some background variables which do not change over time and some other variables like credits taken per semester, and both GPA and cumulative GPA of students on each semester. Since students often had semester breaks and re-admissions, these variables have missing cells (because the data structure is like: one variable for each semester regarding credits taken, GPA and CGPA). I have data for almost 4 years on each semester.

The other problem is that a few students received help from more than one such programs.

We want to see how effective each of these programs is: effectiveness will be measured in terms of the improvement in the GPA or CGPA of the students. We will also like to see if the effect was instant but temporary or instant and durable or delayed but durable or delayed but temporary.

What kind of model can help us to find these things? Could you please suggest?

Comment: A retrospective dataset like this might be useful for exploration and setting up an adequate study in the future, but with so much potential for confounding it seems too much to hope that any analysis could address the questions you are most concerned about. Have you considered the possibility of making some random choices in the awarding of these programs? Although that might make some people uncomfortable, and certainly needs discussion, it would be one effective way--and almost certainly would be the most convincing way--to evaluate the efficacy of these programs.

Comment: @whuber you are right about it. Unfortunately we have only this now and definitely it is not a typical treatment-control version. The study is retrospective in nature. We have planned to compare the receivers of these programs to a dummy control group created by propensity score matching using some background variables- I think that is what we can do at best now. The fact that really very few have received more than one program, keeps our hope alive! I am wondering what kind of model we should use to find the above mentioned aspects from this data.

Comment: Are there any sharp cut-offs in terms of criteria that must be satisfied in order to qualify for such programs, for instance a maximum family income? In that case you could use a regression discontinuity design.

Comment: Since these programs are there for years, it's really difficult to find a sharp cut-off. Thanks Andy.

Comment: But there are some criteria that qualify or disqualify students for certain programs?

Comment: Yes Andy, there are some, actually they consider several things. But can we see if the effect was instant but temporary or instant and durable or delayed but durable or delayed but temporary with regression discontinuity design?

Comment: @Andy, The main problem that I am facing is that the same program was received at different times by the students. So, I may calculate the CGPA before and after the program for the program receivers but how can I calculate the same for the non-receivers? Otherwise is it possible to compare the these two groups? Without a fixed time point of implementing the program, how can I find a before and after CGPA for control group who did not receive any program?

Comment: @whuber I would also like to know your thought.